# What are these parts? Underside of Mercedes Sprinter close to fuel tank

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, part-identification, fuel-tank

These are from underside of Mercedes Sprinter close to fuel tank. One goes to the engine, the other to a diesel heater. I think they're too small to the fuel filters or pumps. What are they?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Diesel heater?  Heats the diesel, or diesel burning heater for the cab?

Comment: Diesel burning heater for the cab and crew area.

Comment: Looks like the pump for an sloppy installed aftermarket cab heater. Do you have two heaters?

Comment: @Martin Just the one heater. 2nd hand purchase. Trying to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that they are electrically operated solenoid valves for shutting off the diesel when the ignition is off.  Looks a bit like this in a rubber mount -

[image]

Taken from - https://12voltfuelvalves.com/product/12-volt-multi-fuel-shut-off-solenoid-valve/

Comment: No way are those Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM) components. Those screws on the heater and the orange wire bundle scream crappy aftermarket / owner add on.  It sure looks like a solenoid, but why would someone add that?  A pump would make a small bit of sense (say you wanted to run the heater when the vehicle is parked overnight) but that would certainly kill a battery pretty quickly. And that only applies to the aux. heater. Why touch the main fuel supply?  Perhaps wacko antitheft application?

Answer (score 1):

if I am looking at the parts you are talking about as you have not circled them, then they could be part of the fuel return system.

Comment: Do diesels have evaporative emissions control equipment?

Comment: @HandyHowie can you smell diesel when filling your tank?

Comment: That isn’t what I asked.  I was asking if they have EVAP.  I can’t find any references to EVAP in diesels.  Do diesels have it fitted?   All references I have found say that diesels do not need EVAP due to the high boiling point.